# how can I revert my files to its initial state using bzr

Tags: bazaar

I have a file and I checkout using the command (BZR CHECKOUT ...). Now, I made a lot of commits and found out there are errors in my codes. I want to revert all my files back to its original form after I first checkout. can anybody help me with a step-by-step process/command. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can revert your pending (= uncommitted) changes with:

```
bzr revert
```

Or if you want to return to the state of a past revision, let's say revision 17, you can do:

```
bzr update -r 17
```